# Xamarin.Forms SFChart DataBinding: Changing bound data objects causes error and crash

Tags: xamarin.forms, mvvmcross, syncfusion-chart

recently, we have discovered an error in my Xamarin.Forms application that seems to be in correlation to the Syncfusion element 'SfChart'.

We have a 4-axis chart that fetches data via data binding. The error occurs when one object that carries the data, used by the chart to draw the lines, is getting removed, added or altered.

This data is stored in an ObservableCollection and signals a PropertyChanged when altered.

Whenever a different data object is assigned to an index of the data list, bound to the ItemSources of the individual FastLineSeries, I sometimes get the following error:

[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index must be within the bounds of the List.

[mono-rt] Parameter name: index

[mono-rt] at System.Collections.Generic.List`1[T].Insert (System.Int32 index, T item) [0x00009] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs:688

[mono-rt] at Com.Syncfusion.Charts.ChartSeries.SetIndividualPoint (System.Int32 index, System.Object value, System.Boolean replace) [0x007d4] in <5223039dbed24acb9c9c1764d59d17de>:0

[mono-rt] at Com.Syncfusion.Charts.ChartSeries.OnDataSource_CollectionChanged (System.Object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00041] in <5223039dbed24acb9c9c1764d59d17de>:0

[mono-rt] at (wrapper delegate-invoke) .invoke_void_object_NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(object,System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs)

[mono-rt] at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1[T].OnCollectionChanged (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) [0x00018] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.ObjectModel/src/System/Collections/ObjectModel/ObservableCollection.cs:263

[mono-rt] at MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxObservableCollection`1[T].<>n__0 (System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e) <0x727c3f6d68 + 0x00043> in <687f2e5f7efd4e33b498a18ba9db221f>:0

[mono-rt] at MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxObservableCollection`1+<>c_DisplayClass7_0[T].b0 () [0x00000] in //MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxObservableCollection.cs:72

[mono-rt] at MvvmCross.Base.MvxMainThreadAsyncDispatcher+<>c_DisplayClass0_0.b0 () [0x00000] in //MvvmCross/Base/MvxMainThreadAsyncDispatcher.cs:16

[mono-rt] at MvvmCross.Base.MvxMainThreadAsyncDispatcher+<>c_DisplayClass1_0.b0 () [0x00011] in //MvvmCross/Base/MvxMainThreadAsyncDispatcher.cs:27

[mono-rt] at (wrapper dynamic-method) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.26(intptr,intptr)

[mono-rt] at (wrapper native-to-managed) Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.26(intptr,intptr)

It also seems that sometimes after changing or deleting the data for the LineSeries, old data is retained in the UI element and two of the same LineSeries with the same color gets drawn, even if this data isn't anywhere in the data bound list.

What's weird is that two lines with the same color and a big value difference get drawn by the chart, although there only is one possible binding that one LineSeries should be able to get data from.

Best regards,
O.B.

[The picture shows the chart with the wrong double yellow lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Jzyx.png)

The XAML looks like this:

```
       <Grid
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        BackgroundColor="#0072BC"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapChartSelectionPopup}" CommandParameter="0" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BackgroundColor="#ED1B2F"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Text="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[0].Name}" />
                        <Label
                            x:Name="UnitLabel1"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Text="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[0].Unit}"
                            TextColor="White"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Image
                            Grid.Column="6"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Margin="0,0,-5,0"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Scale="0.7"
                            Source="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[0].ImagePath}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        BackgroundColor="#0072BC"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapChartSelectionPopup}" CommandParameter="1" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BackgroundColor="#8DC63F"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Text="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[1].Name}" />
                        <Label
                            x:Name="UnitLabel2"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Text="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[1].Unit}"
                            TextColor="White"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Image
                            Grid.Column="6"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Margin="0,0,-5,0"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Scale="0.7"
                            Source="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[1].ImagePath}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        BackgroundColor="#0072BC"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapChartSelectionPopup}" CommandParameter="2" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BackgroundColor="#07426E"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Text="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[2].Name}" />
                        <Label
                            x:Name="UnitLabel3"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Text="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[2].Unit}"
                            TextColor="White"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Image
                            Grid.Column="6"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Margin="0,0,-5,0"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Scale="0.7"
                            Source="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[2].ImagePath}" />
                    </Grid>

                    <Grid
                        Grid.Row="1"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        BackgroundColor="#0072BC"
                        HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapChartSelectionPopup}" CommandParameter="3" />
                        </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="0"
                            BackgroundColor="#FFCC00"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Label
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                            Text="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[3].Name}" />
                        <Label
                            x:Name="UnitLabel4"
                            Grid.Column="5"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            Text="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[3].Unit}"
                            TextColor="White"
                            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                        <Image
                            Grid.Column="6"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Margin="0,0,-5,0"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            Scale="0.7"
                            Source="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[3].ImagePath}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>

            <StackLayout
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Orientation="Horizontal"
                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                       Property=Height,
                                                                       Factor=0.75}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                      Property=Width,
                                                                      Factor=0.9}"
                RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                  Property=Width,
                                                                  Factor=0.05}"
                RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
                                                                  Property=Height,
                                                                  Factor=0.25}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">


                <sfChart:SfChart
                    x:Name="chart"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <sfChart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>
                        <sfChart:DateTimeAxis />
                    </sfChart:SfChart.PrimaryAxis>

                    <sfChart:SfChart.ChartBehaviors>
                        <sfChart:ChartZoomPanBehavior EnableDirectionalZooming="True" EnableDoubleTap="True" />
                    </sfChart:SfChart.ChartBehaviors>

                    <sfChart:SfChart.Series>
                        <sfChart:FastLineSeries
                            x:Name="flSeries1"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[0].ChartDataLog}"
                            XBindingPath="TestDT"
                            YBindingPath="Value"
                            Color="#ED1B2F" />
                        <sfChart:FastLineSeries
                            x:Name="flSeries2"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[1].ChartDataLog}"
                            XBindingPath="TestDT"
                            YBindingPath="Value"
                            Color="#8DC63F" />
                        <sfChart:FastLineSeries
                            x:Name="flSeries3"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[2].ChartDataLog}"
                            XBindingPath="TestDT"
                            YBindingPath="Value"
                            Color="#07426E" />
                        <sfChart:FastLineSeries
                            x:Name="flSeries4"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding PanelAppModel.PanelApp.ChartModel.ChartDataList[3].ChartDataLog}"
                            XBindingPath="TestDT"
                            YBindingPath="Value"
                            Color="#FFCC00" />

                    </sfChart:SfChart.Series>

                </sfChart:SfChart>
            </StackLayout>
```

Comment: The index being outside of bounds of list suggests that some code is changing the list (adding/removing item, as you mentioned) at the same time as the UI is attempting to update the view. Your code that adds/removes item: could that be running on a **background thread**?  Its only safe to alter the list from the UI thread; use `Xamarin.Essentials.MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread` or Xamarin Forms `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, if necessary.